# The method getActivity in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguements

Tags: java, android, sms

I am getting this error while implementing SMS sending in android. Attaching the image as the error is too long :)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit hard to see but try this.

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(<YourActivityClass>.this, 0, ...
```